# Variable Problem when coding the Player Movement in GameMaker Studio 1.4.9999

Tags: animation, game-maker

In oGirlTest object I have a Create and Step event.

Create:

```
///PLAYER OBJECT CREATE EVENT

//Maximum speed
spd = 4;

//Current movement speed
hspd = 0;
vspd = 0;

//Initialize basic properties
sprite_index = sPlayerDown;
image_speed = 0.5;

//Initialize basic movement state
state = move_state;

/*

Directions for top-down spritework.

0 = down
1 = left
2 = up
3 = right

*/

dir = 0;
```

Step:

```
///PLAYER OBJECT STEP EVENT

//Get input (keyboard/controller)
get_input();

//Execute the state (in the basic case, this calls the move_state script)
script_execute(state);
```

And 3 scripts that I've found and which I'm trying to understand in order to replicate the Undertale movement

get_input

```
///get_input()

left = keyboard_check(vk_left);
right = keyboard_check(vk_right);
up = keyboard_check(vk_up);
down = keyboard_check(vk_down);
```

move_state

```
///move_state

//Set animation speed for movement

image_speed = 1;

//Set default speed if there is no input

hspd = 0;
vspd = 0;

//Set speed to the direction you are pressing as long as there isn't a wall there
//Left and up take precedence

if(right && !place_meeting(x+1,y,Solid)) hspd = spd;

if(left && !place_meeting(x-1,y,Solid)) hspd = -spd;

if(down && !place_meeting(x,y+1,Solid)) vspd = spd;

if(up && !place_meeting(x,y-1,Solid)) vspd = -spd;

//Prevent stuttering if against a wall pressing opposite directional buttons

/*

SPECIAL NOTE: The following two lines of uncommented code deviate from Undertale.
In Undertale if you hold both UP & DOWN at the same time and run into a wall,
your character will stutter against it. Also if you hold LEFT & RIGHT and run into a wall,
your character will stop in its tracks. I fixed those issues in the next two lines of uncommented code.
if you truly wanted an exact replica of Undertale, replace them with this instead:

if(left && right && place_meeting(x-1,y,Solid))
{
hspd = 0;
vspd = 0;
}

This will replicate the stuttering effect and the freeze effect you encounter in Undertale.

*/

if(left && right && place_meeting(x-1,y,Solid)) hspd = 0;

if(up && down && place_meeting(x,y-1,Solid)) vspd = 0;

//Set the sprite to the appropriate direction

if(hspd < 0) sprite_index = sPlayerLeft;

if(hspd > 0) sprite_index = sPlayerRight;

if(vspd < 0) sprite_index = sPlayerUp;

if(vspd > 0) sprite_index = sPlayerDown;

//Sprite direction correction in special cases of multiple button press combinations

if((right && down && left && !up) || (right && down && !left && !up && dir == 1) || (left && down && !right && !up && dir == 3)) dir = 0;

if((down && left && up && !right) || (down && left && !up && !right && dir == 2) || (up && left && !right && !down && dir == 0)) dir = 1;

if((left && up && right && !down) || (left && up && !right && !down && dir == 3) || (right && up && !down && !left && dir == 1)) dir = 2;

if((up && right && down && !left) || (up && right && !down && !left && dir == 0) || (down && right && !up && !left && dir == 2)) dir = 3;

//Maintain sprite momentum by checking the previous sprite direction

if(hspd < 0 && dir == 1 && left) sprite_index = sPlayerLeft;

if(hspd > 0 && dir == 3 && right) sprite_index = sPlayerRight;

if(vspd < 0 && dir = 2 && up) sprite_index = sPlayerUp;

if(vspd > 0 && dir = 0 && down) sprite_index = sPlayerDown;

//Special checks when you're up against a wall trying to move against or along it

if(sprite_index == sPlayerLeft)
{
    if(place_meeting(x-1,y,Solid))
{
   if(vspd > 0 && !place_meeting(x,y+1,Solid))
   {
       sprite_index = sPlayerDown;
       dir = 3;
   }
   else if(vspd < 0 && !place_meeting(x,y-1,Solid))
   {
       sprite_index = sPlayerUp;
       dir = 1;
   }
   else
   {
       hspd = 0;
       vspd = 0;
   }
}
     else dir = 1;
}

    if(sprite_index == sPlayerRight)
    {
    if(place_meeting(x+1,y,Solid))
    {
        if(vspd > 0 && !place_meeting(x,y+1,Solid))
    {
        sprite_index = sPlayerDown;
       dir = 3;
    }
       else if(vspd < 0 && !place_meeting(x,y-1,Solid))
   {
       sprite_index = sPlayerUp;
       dir = 1;
   }
   else
   {
       hspd = 0;
       vspd = 0;
   }
 }
else dir = 3;
}

    if(sprite_index == sPlayerUp)
 {
    if(place_meeting(x,y-1,Solid))
 {
   if(hspd > 0 && !place_meeting(x+1,y,Solid))
   {
       sprite_index = sPlayerRight;
       dir = 3;
   }
   else if(hspd < 0 && !place_meeting(x-1,y,Solid))
   {
       sprite_index = sPlayerLeft;
       dir = 1;
   }
   else
   {
       hspd = 0;
       vspd = 0;
   }
 }
else dir = 2;
    }

    if(sprite_index == sPlayerDown)
    {
 if(place_meeting(x,y+1,Solid))
 {
   if(hspd > 0 && !place_meeting(x+1,y,Solid))
   {
       sprite_index = sPlayerRight;
       dir = 3;
   }
   else if(hspd < 0 && !place_meeting(x-1,y,Solid))
   {
       sprite_index = sPlayerLeft;
       dir = 1;
   }
   else
   {
       hspd = 0;
       vspd = 0;
   }
 }
else dir = 0;
}

//If there is no input, default to the idle state

if(hspd == 0 && vspd == 0)
{
sprite_index = sPlayerDown;
image_speed = 0.5;
}

//Actually move the player

move(Solid);
```

move

```
///move(collision_object)

var collision_object = argument0;

//Horizontal collisions

if(place_meeting(x+hspd,y,collision_object))
{
  while(!place_meeting(x+sign(hspd),y,collision_object))
 {
    x += sign(hspd);
 }
hspd = 0;
}

x += hspd;

//Vertical collisions

if(place_meeting(x,y+vspd,collision_object))
{
while(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vspd),collision_object))
{
       y += sign(vspd);
}
  vspd = 0;
}

y += vspd;
```

And I'm getting the following error, for another person this script worked so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I apologize for the wall of text, just trying to understand.

```
___________________________________________
############################################################################################
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Event0
for object oGirlTest:

Variable oGirlTest.Solid(100008, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
at gml_Script_move_state (line 150) -      if(place_meeting(x,y+1,Solid))
############################################################################################
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stack frame is
gml_Script_move_state (line 150)
called from - gml_Object_oGirlTest_StepNormalEvent_1 (line 7) -     script_execute(state);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Place_meeting` is used to reach a different instance, so `Solid` should be the name of that instance it's colliding with. Your Gamemaker cannot recognise an instance named `Solid`(it's Case-sensitive), so it assumes that `Solid` is a custom variable from oGirlTest.

So you need to create (or rename) an instance that's called `Solid`, and use that as the walls you're colliding with. Once it can recognise an instance correctly, the text should be turn dark red.